# Why does Unity 2D start when I choose the "GNOME/Openbox" session?

Tags: gnome, unity-2d, openbox

I have Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity 2D and Gnome Shell, and I have also installed the Openbox window manager.

If I choose to start an "Openbox" session, it works fine (i.e. the Openbox window manager starts), but if I choose the "GNOME/Openbox" session, then Unity 2D starts.

Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

That is because your GNOME installation was installed as a dependency from another package(usually when someone installs gnome-tweak-tool, and gets a bunch of other gnome packages) If you want to fix this, then I suggest first removing Gnome3, and then re-installing it. And if you want unity to go away temporarily then use "killall unity-2d" and "gnome-panel" commands...